# Javascript - call a script that is already using functions

Tags: javascript, function, methods

thanks for taking the time reading this. 
I have a code snippet that has already some functions inside. Now I want to run that script if a button was clicked. From what I've tested it seems like it's not possible to put the snippet with its functions into a parent function *(, is it?)*.

Now I wonder, **what is the best way to call the javascript code snippet?**

I don't think that is important for this general question, but here's my script I want to call:

```
var $input = $( '.datepicker2' ).pickadate({

        })

        var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
        var plusDays = 1;
        var currentSelection = picker.get();
        var currentDay;
        var currentMonth;
        var currentYear;
        var newDay;

        strich = currentSelection.indexOf("-");
        currentYear = currentSelection.substring(0, strich);

        strich = currentSelection.indexOf("-");
        currentMonth = currentSelection.substring(strich + 1);
        strich = currentMonth.indexOf("-");
        currentMonth = currentMonth.substring(0, strich);

        strich = currentSelection.indexOf("-");
        currentDay = currentSelection.substring(strich + 1);
        strich = currentDay.indexOf("-");
        currentDay = currentDay.substring(strich + 1);

        newDay = parseInt(currentDay) + plusDays;

        var $input = $( '.datepicker' ).pickadate({

        })

        var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
        var date = new Date()
        picker.set('select', [currentYear, currentMonth - 1, newDay])
```

Comment: It is "put into a function" by using `function some_name (some, parameters) { /* some code */ }`; and yes, it is possible. If it "doesn't work", then find out why and fix *that* issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are:

```
function snippet() {
    var $input = $( '.datepicker2' ).pickadate({});

    var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
    var plusDays = 1;
    var currentSelection = picker.get();
    var currentDay;
    var currentMonth;
    var currentYear;
    var newDay;

    strich = currentSelection.indexOf("-");
    currentYear = currentSelection.substring(0, strich);

    strich = currentSelection.indexOf("-");
    currentMonth = currentSelection.substring(strich + 1);
    strich = currentMonth.indexOf("-");
    currentMonth = currentMonth.substring(0, strich);

    strich = currentSelection.indexOf("-");
    currentDay = currentSelection.substring(strich + 1);
    strich = currentDay.indexOf("-");
    currentDay = currentDay.substring(strich + 1);

    newDay = parseInt(currentDay) + plusDays;

    var $input = $( '.datepicker' ).pickadate({

    })

    var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
    var date = new Date()
    picker.set('select', [currentYear, currentMonth - 1, newDay])
}
```

And you can call everywhere, everytime you need:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     //stuff
     snippet() ;
 });
```

If you have a function inside the function (like this)

```
function snippet() {
    var $input = $( '.datepicker2' ).pickadate({});

    var picker = $input.pickadate('picker')
    var plusDays = 1;
    var currentSelection = picker.get();
    var currentDay;
    this.anotherFunction = function() {
           // some stuff
    }
}
```

You can call it:

```
 snippet.anotherFunction();
```

Good luck

Comment: Hey there, especially the last part of your answer helped a lot! Thanks!